# Differential equations on symplectic manifolds in Darboux´s coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symplectic-geometry

I´m currently reading about symplectic manifolds and Darboux theorem in "Introduction to Symplectic Topology " (by McDuff and Salamon) and "Symplectic invariants and Hamiltonian Dynamics" (by Hofer and Zehnder).

To get to my question: I came across this statement:

Let (M,$\omega$) be a symplectic manifold and let $H_t:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ Denote by $X_{H_t}$ the (unique) Hamiltonian vector field determined by
\begin{align*}
\omega(X_{H_t}, \cdot)= dH_t
\end{align*}
for each t. In symplectic coordinates provided by Darboux´s theorem the ODE
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}(t)=X_{H_t}(x(t))
\end{align*}
is nothing but the Hamiltonian differential equation.

I don´t seam to get why this ODE is the Hamiltonian differential equation. Can somebody give me a hint, recommend another source or spell it out for  me?

Thanks for taking the time out of your day to read/answer my question.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what the Hamiltonian differential (system of) equation(s) is? Do you understand how a system of ODEs is the same as a vector field in coordinates? Have you tried translating the equation of $X_{H_t}$ into such as system of ODEs in Darboux coordinates?

Comment: I know that in Darbou´x coordinates the 2-form $\omega$ is equal to the standard symplectic form $\omega_0$ which in turn can be represented by a 2n x 2n matrix $J_0.$  Using this we get that $dH_t(\cdot)=\omega_0(X_{H_t},\cdot)=-X_{H_t}^T J_0 \cdot.$
Can we just rearrange it to get to $-J_0 \nabla H_t = X_{H_t}$?

Comment: What you wrote involves various extra identifications (for example of forms with vector fields). You can do it that way, after spelling out those identifications, but it's not the simplest way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\omega=\sum dx_i\wedge dy_i$ one gets that for $X=\sum a_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}+b_i\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}$ we have $\omega(X, \cdot)=\sum a_i dy_i-b_i dx_i$. Thus to get $dH=\sum \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i} dx_i+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_i} dy_i$ we must have $X_H=\sum \frac{\partial H}{\partial y_i}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}$, which encodes the ODE system $ x_i'=\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_i}, y_i'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_i}$ aka the Hamiltonian ODE system.

Note that this is all done in a particular set of conventions.  See: https://symplecticfieldtheorist.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/signs-or-how-to-annoy-a-symplectic-topologist/